# Pagination in Rails controller using Kaminari

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller, pagination

I'm using Kaminari for some pagination but getting the following error when trying to see my index action:

> undefined method `to_i' for {:page=>1}:Hash

The controllers index action is:

```
def index
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html do
      @coasters = Coaster.scoped.page(page: (params[:page] || 1))
    end
  end
end
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`page` requires an integer or an object that responds to `to_i` as an argument.

```
@coasters = Coaster.scoped.page(params[:page] || 1)
```